# Web Scraping using XPath - Not finding element after copying text xpath

Tags: python, html, xpath, python-requests, lxml

Trying to get a specific portion of text from this web page... trying to use code I found from a similar post:

```
# Import required modules
from lxml import html
import requests
  
# Request the page
page = requests.get('https://www.baseball-reference.com/players/k/kershcl01.shtml')
  
# Parsing the page
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
  
# Get element using XPath
share = tree.xpath(
    '//div[@id="leaderboard_cyyoung"]/table/tbody/tr[11]/td/a')
print(share)
```

Output is just empty brackets []

Comment: cut off segments from the right side of the path until something is hit, then trace out where you went wrong to the right of that point.

Comment: What specifically is your desired output?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting empty results because the `div` element you are trying to query is commented out in the requested page's source. Note that when you use the `requests.get` method, you get the **page's HTML source code**, not the **rendered HTML code** generated by the browser from your interaction with the page and that you can inspect with the browser's developer tools.

So I would say: check again if this is really the element you see rendered on the page and see if you can identify what kind of interaction makes it rendered. Then you can use a tool to mock this interaction so that you can get the rendered HTML code within your Python environment. I would suggest [helium](https://github.com/mherrmann/selenium-python-helium) for doing so. If this is not the right element, you can simply update the specified XPath to get the right source-code available element and successfully scrape it.

Answer (score 0):

As stated, this is rendered/dynamic part of the site. It is there in the comments, so you'll need to pull out the comments of the html, then parse. The other issue with it is in the comments, there is no `<tbody>` tag, so it wont find anything, you'd need to remove that. I'm not sure what you want to pull out though (is it the link, is it the text?). I alerted your code to show you how to use it with lxml, but hoestly not a fan. I'd prefer to just use BeautifulSoup. BeautifulSoup however doesn't intigrate with xpath, so used css selector instead.

**Your code altered:**

```
import requests
from lxml import html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment

headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.104 Safari/537.36'}

url = "https://www.baseball-reference.com/players/k/kershcl01.shtml"

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
comments = soup.find_all(string=lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment))


for each in comments:
    if 'leaderboard_cyyoung' in str(each):
        htmlStr = str(each)   

        # Parsing the page
        tree = html.fromstring(htmlStr)
          
        # Get element using XPath
        share = tree.xpath('//div[@id="leaderboard_cyyoung"]/table/tr[11]/td/a')
        print(share)
```

**How I would do it:**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment

headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.104 Safari/537.36'}

url = "https://www.baseball-reference.com/players/k/kershcl01.shtml"

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
comments = soup.find_all(string=lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment))

for each in comments:
    if 'leaderboard_cyyoung' in str(each):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(str(each), 'html.parser')
        share = soup.select('div#leaderboard_cyyoung > table > tr:nth-child(12) > td > a')
        print(share)
        break
```

**Output:**

```
[<a href="/leaders/mvp_cya.shtml">4.58 Career Shares</a>]
```